# ASP.NET vb.net "The conversion of char data type to smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range smalldatetime value."

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, calendar, smalldatetime

I'm using calendar from tool box of VS IDE, and I want to get data from database according to selected date from calendar between 20/7/2020 to 20/7/2021, but I got an error

> The conversion of char data type to smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range smalldatetime value. VB.Net

I have a calendar control:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="calFrom" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMsv8.png)

Comment: That error message is from the database, possibly when you're trying to save data. You need to determine exactly where the error occurs - that's why exceptions have a stack trace - and provide us with the relevant code. Also, when you upload an image and it adds the default text "enter image description here", you're supposed to enter the image description there. Why should we follow a link with zero explanation?

Comment: If SQL Server, use try_convert() with the culture code.  Example:  Select try_convert(datetime,'20/7/2020',103)

Comment: There is more than one way it can go wrong. Please [edit] the question so we can see the code that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Many thanks Mr.  
John Cappelletti
It's worked

Comment: @user2501024 If that worked, then you're doing it wrong. You should use the .SelectedDate property of the calendar control and pass the date using an SqlParameter to the database, not as a string.

Comment: already selectedDate Pro. is used, but how i can send it as a parameter so i used SQLdataAdaptor variable ?

Comment: @user2501024 If you train Google by searching for things like that, it will get better at suggesting things like [DataAdapter Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapter-parameters) ;)